# Dynamically allocate 2 dimensional array purely using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to reverse the words of the string (not the words itself). I am trying to dynamically allocate 2 dimensional array only using pointers(not using array syntax). My program compiles fine but end up displaying only one word as output with spaces here and there. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void rev(char *x, int n);
int words(char * p);

int main()
{
    char *p = (char *)malloc(101*sizeof(char));
    fgets(p, 101, stdin);
    rev(p, words(p));
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

void rev(char *x, int n)
{
    char **y = (char **)malloc(101*sizeof(char *));
    int i = 0;

    int *j = (int *)calloc(101, sizeof(int));
    *y = (char *)malloc(101*sizeof(char));
    while(*x!='\n')
    {
        if(*x==' ')
        {
            i++;
            *(y+i) = (char *)malloc(101*sizeof(char));
        }
        else
        {

            *(*(y+i)+(*(j+i))) = *x;
            (*(j+i))++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    i++;
    int z, q;
    for(z=i-1; z>0; z--)
    {
        for(q=0; q<(*(j+i)); q++)
        {
            printf("%c", *(*(y+z)+(q)));
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(q=0; q<*j; q++)
    {
        printf("%c", *(*(y)+(q)));
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(q=0; q<i; q++)
    {
        free(y+i);
    }
    free(j);
    free(y);
}

int words(char * p)
{
    int x = 0;
    while(*p!='\n')
    {
        if(*p==' ')
        {
            x++;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return ++x;
}
```

I want to do it only using pointer arithmetic. I have been trying it for past 20 hours and couldn't figure it out. Can anybody explain the mistake and how to correct it?
Input
`Hello World`
Output

```
 Hello
```

Input
`This is my input`
Output

```
    This
```

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. `char **` is **not** a 2D array and cannot point to one. A pointer is not an array or vice-versa. And don't use _magic numbers_.

Comment: `for(q=0; q<i; q++){ free(y+i);}` and `for(q=0; q<i; q++){ free(j+i);}` seems bad because they are using meaningless loop or do `free` for same pointer multiple times.

Comment: @MikeCAT Is it due to this mistake, I am not getting required output ?

Comment: Do you have working code using arrays?

Comment: It is good to show us some examples of input and desired output.

Comment: [Your program crashed](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jYyuNgjwfZCeAeOX).

Comment: "end up displaying only one word as output with spaces here and there" [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zX3YVbTQKUCeC1hY) after removing the problematic `free`s. Some undefined behavior...?

Comment: @MikeCAT I added input and output. I am using codeblocks. It is compiling and not showing any warnings in my IDE

Comment: Please show your *desired* output. Posting actual output is somewhat helpful, but we can get them by executing the code. Also I advice that first you should use array to build working program, then convert it to pointer aritimetic using `E1[E2]` = `*((E1)+(E2))` rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really tricky problem (Reversing the words in a string). One of the best solutions for this problem is that you define a function to reverse the whole string, then start reading word by word of the resulting string and if you arrive to an space, again use the reverse function and print it.

**Original String**

> hello world

**First Step**

> dlrow olleh

**Second Step**

> world hello

This solution is much easier than your complicated solution.

This can be a possible `reverse` function which I mentioned above:

```
void rev(char *word, int len)
{
  char c;
  if(len>1)
  {
    c=word[len-1];
    word[len-1]=word[0];
    word[0]=c;
    rev(word+1, len-2);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your new approach

Comment: @bharadwaj you're welcome, if it helped, please mark my answer as the correct one

Comment: Your approach did really help. Indeed I will use your approach from now on. But I cannot mark your answer as correct one as that is not the one I asked.

Comment: It's okay, If you need help with my approach ask again, best of luck. @bharadwaj